# SQL - Selecting rows with max sums, efficiency

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am selecting from table player_info, and the row with the max(sum()) of column time_played of table player_map_info. The primary key of player_map_info is (player_id, color, map), and I want to get the color with the most time played, across all maps.

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT A.*, 
       B.color AS main_color, 
       B.maxtp 
FROM   player_info A 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT E.player_id, 
                               E.color, 
                               Max(sumtp) AS maxtp 
                        FROM   player_map_info C 
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT player_id, 
                                                       color, 
                                                       Sum(time_played) AS sumtp 
                                                FROM   player_map_info 
                                                GROUP  BY player_id, 
                                                          color) E 
                                            ON C.player_id = E.player_id 
                                               AND C.color = E.color 
                        GROUP  BY E.player_id) B 
                    ON A.player_id = B.player_id 
WHERE  A.user_id = :user_id
```

I'm using SQLite. It takes just under 0.1 sec to execute this on my database.

Question: Is there any way to make this query perform faster? (I'm quite new to all the nuances of joining and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

Just take out stuff related to users:

```
SELECT C.color, maxtp 
FROM   player_map_info C 
inner join (SELECT max(time_played) AS maxtp 
                FROM   player_map_info 
                ) mx
) B ON c.time_played = mx.maxtp
```

Inner query mx gets the max time_played, and the outer query joins back to it to get the color. That gets the most played color.

To make it faster. Well, at 0.1 seconds you're unlikely to make any large increases.

Cheers -